# A cubical LC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, inductor

I would like to solve for currents through inductors and the voltage across capacitances of the attached circuit. I am trying to figure out a correct method to solve such circuits which could have the circuit in the image as one of the elements. The voltage is a sinusoidal AC voltage of frequency w. If this problem is simple and there is a reference, please just guide me to that and I can look up and try it further. Thanks a lot in advance :-) 
[image: LC circuit on a cube]

Comment: Huh? What is "energy" of a circuit?  You say you want to "solve" the circuit, but failed to specify what parameters you want to solve for.  We do engineering here, not hand waving.  Get real or get closed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I am happy that you don't do hand waving. I want to calculate what is required to calculate the energy due to capacitances and inductors in the circuit. So, I need the current through each inductor and the voltage across each capacitance. I am not much of an engineer :-) but I hope I am right.

Comment: "Energy from each element" and "current accross each inductor" is just more gibberish.

Comment: Is it a dc supply and you want to therefore know what the cap voltages are charged up to - because it's dc there will be only a transient current through the inductors unless you are considering them lossless components and then, quite possibly there will be a sinusoidal content due to it being a perfect resonant circuit.

Comment: Like Olin says - what does the "energy from each element" mean AND take note, current flows thru components and not across them - that particular descriptor applies to voltages.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks, I made the correction. I suppose I want to take any capacitance and know the charge stored on it at any time and take any inductor and know the current through it. The voltage is AC. Thanks for the clarifications. I hope my question is clear. When we do such circuits on nanoscale, we usually like to write down the Hamiltonian which basically describes the energy due to the circuit. I agree that is sort of a misnomer but that is where I used it from.

Comment: You need to do about 2 or 3 pages of algebra to solve for the currents.

Comment: Try drawing it out as a 2D circuit

Comment: How about [mesh analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis)?

Comment: Are you familiar with Delta-Wye transformations?

Comment: Cleanplay, if the source is sinusoidal, you surely know that you can replace each inductor and capacitor with it's impedance.  Then you can solve for the circuit voltages and currents much like you would if the circuit elements were resistors and a DC source except that, of course, you're working with impedances and phasor voltages and currents.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : If you have never heard the phrase 'energy of a circuit' and 'energy from a circuit element' before, you can refer the sections Conclusion and LC Circuit dynamics of this IEEE paper on page 81 here :- http://doc.utwente.nl/30185/1/schaft95intrinsic.pdf

Answer (score 4):

As stated, the answer is unknowable if the DC components of the voltages (and therefor of the capacitor energies) are desired. The circuit can be redrawn as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkZOlZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At DC, the impedance of the inductors is zero, and the output of the sine wave generator is zero, so the circuit becomes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRQz0J.png)</sup>

Consequently, the voltages V1/V2 and V3/V4 can be any values at all, and the voltages across the capacitors are (in absolute terms) impossible to determine. Even if you assume that the sine generator has some non-zero voltage at DC, the values of V1/V2 and V3/V4 can still be anything at all.

Note that you cannot assume that V1/V2 and V3/V4 are zero. There is nothing presented so far that allows that assumption (or conclusion, take your pick).

Answer (score 0):

I certainly don't want to calculate it, but it seems I have to go through two C's and one L to get from in to out, so I'll guess the resonant frequency is something like 1/Sqrt(LC/2)  Will you build one and measure it?

(oops, units of radians per second since I left out the 2*pi)